# DotNetCore NPOI AutoSizeColumn Too Narrow

Tags: c#, npoi

I'm using NPOI and C# and cannot seem to get AutoSizeColumn to size the columns appropriately. I've followed the suggestions I can find, set the font up front in the styles, added content after the styles are applied, auto-sized the columns before write (after all data is added) and still the columns are too narrow.  Below is a demonstration of the problem:

```cs
public void ShowBug()
{
    IWorkbook workbook;
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    // Create a base font
    IFont boldFont = workbook.CreateFont();
    boldFont.FontHeightInPoints = 11;
    boldFont.FontName = "Calibri";
    boldFont.Boldweight = (short)FontBoldWeight.Bold;

    // Create a base style
    ICellStyle boldStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
    boldStyle.SetFont(boldFont);

    // Create a simple cell style using the base style
    ICellStyle simpleStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
    simpleStyle.CloneStyleFrom(boldStyle);

    // Create a sheet in the workbook
    ISheet excelSheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Demo");

    // Create a single row
    IRow row = excelSheet.CreateRow(0);

    // Create a single cell inside the row
    ICell cell = row.CreateCell(0);
    cell.SetCellType(CellType.String);
    cell.CellStyle = simpleStyle;
    cell.SetCellValue("This is an icredibly long text value for this column - and apparently too long");

    // Autosize the column and create the file, after the output is produced
    using (var fs = new FileStream("BugReport.xlsx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        excelSheet.AutoSizeColumn(0, true);
        workbook.Write(fs);
    }
}
```

This code shows up in Excel like this:

[Result of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XnTx.png)

So, what am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I am using this approach to auto size the column header

```
 XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet)workbook.CreateSheet("Demo");
 sheet.AutoSizeColumn(“header1”); // Remove Boolean value which you are passing
```

Comment: What is header1?

Comment: “Header1” is  header name. Either you can pass header name as string or index. Please see the code  in question and my code reference is for that.